# Duplicated advertisements on the side

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-design

When browsing a question, sometimes a duplicate set of advertisements shows up on the right hand side:

> [image]

While nothing is *wrong* with this, the duplicate advertisements could either be used to show two, different adverts, or appear to be not quite as desperate for eyeballs and advertisers that it's showing the same thing twice, on the same page.

Comment: Interesting. I've never noticed this. Is it just something that happens "now and then," or have you been able to identify any sort of pattern for when it occurs?

Comment: @MatthewHaugen nope.  I haven't noticed any pattern at this time, though I also don't tend to browse this StackExchange too much to be sure.

Comment: Interesting. Yeah, this seems like something that would be pretty clear to anyone looking at the code, I was just curious. Good catch!

Comment: Have you seen it more than once? Also: when was the first instance of this issue? @MichaelT (Note: I see it too)

Answer (score 4):

Nice catch! Not sure why this wasn't caught sooner, actually!

Regardless: I've updated things on our end so that shouldn't happen anymore. Expect it to occur a little while longer while the duplicated creative ramps down.

Ping me here if you see it again after tomorrow.

Thanks!

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Comment: @hichris123 Yep! Thanks for the reminder! Updated!

Comment: Wow, didn't expect a response on Thanksgiving. Now go back to your family. ;)